# Batch Broadcast of Vector in element-wise calculation

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to take a batch of vectors and perform a element wise subtraction with broad cast to get a matrix of the different between all combinations.  I can get this to work with a batch of length 1, but when I try to increase the number of samples I get all sorts of shape matching errors and don't believe it is broadcasting any longer.  Here is the sample code that gets the single batch working, and a few other inputs I have tried without success to get a batch of 2 working:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#initx = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
#initx = [[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]],[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]]
initx = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

deltas = tf.sub(x,tf.transpose(x))

reshaped_deltas = tf.reshape(deltas,[-1])

with tf.Session('') as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())   

  print "Delta:",session.run([deltas],feed_dict={x:initx })
  print "Flattened Output:",session.run([reshaped_deltas],feed_dict={x:initx })
```

I get the expected result for the single example:

```
Delta: [array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-3., -2., -1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)]
Flattened Output: [array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2., -2., -1.,  0.,  1., -3.,
       -2., -1.,  0.], dtype=float32)]
```

I just can't figure out how to get the "tf.sub()" function to work with batches and still broadcast the [1,4] vector properly for each batch.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I know there is a tf.batch_matmul() but not a batch_sub() which would likely solve the problem.

EDIT: Updated Script to solve problem based upon Yaroslav Bulatov's feedback

```
import tensorflow as tf

initx = [[1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
#initx = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]

VectorSize = len(initx[1])

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

batch1 = tf.reshape(x, (-1,VectorSize, 1))
deltas = tf.sub(batch1, tf.transpose(batch1, (0, 2, 1)))

reshaped_deltas = tf.reshape(deltas,[-1])

with tf.Session('') as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())   

  print "Delta:",session.run([deltas],feed_dict={x:initx })
  print "Flattened Output:",session.run([reshaped_deltas],feed_dict={x:initx })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your batch size is `n` and your data size is `k`. If your inputs to `sub` have shapes `n, k, 1` and `n, 1, k`, broadcasting will fill singleton dimensions to output result of shape `n, k, k` which is what you want. So could use `tf.reshape` to turn your original to `n, k, 1` and `tf.transpose(..., perm=(0, 2, 1))` to get the `n, 1, k` shape. IE, something like this

```
x1 = tf.constant([1,2,3])
x2 = tf.constant([4,4,5])
batch = tf.pack([x1,x2])
n = 2
k = 3
batch1 = tf.reshape(batch, (n, k, 1))
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.sub(batch1, tf.transpose(batch1, (0, 2, 1))))

Out[] = array([[[ 0, -1, -2],
        [ 1,  0, -1],
        [ 2,  1,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0, -1],
        [ 0,  0, -1],
        [ 1,  1,  0]]], dtype=int32)
```